# Tabulator - how do i get rowContextMenu to show on iOS Safari Mobile?

Tags: ios, safari, tabulator

I've defined a rowContextMenu for my tabulator grid (version 4.6), and it is working perfectly on all browsers except Mobile Safari (iPhone, iPad).  In Chrome, Firefox, etc it comes up fine, when I'm using an android device, tap-hold works as a right-click as well.  But on an iPhone, it doesn't, just get the copy/paste menu.  Is there something I'm missing or does this feature not work on iOS? (I don't own an iPhone, so I recently discovered it from my co-workers.)

Comment: You should file an issue on the github project. Make sure to follow the template when creating the issue, so that it has all of the necessary information.

Comment: From a suggested edit: *"A bug was reported via Github (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2847) on 6/20/2020."*

Answer (score 0):

As of version 4.8 (to be released the first weekend of September 2020) context menus will be available via a tapHold action on mobile devices